# Modify part of border in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, format

In this sheet which I have inherited I need to modify only the highlighted horizontal border in the pic, whilst keeping the other borders.

[Modify only border highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znvSd.png)

I feel really embarrased to admit that I know how to do this in a horrible tool called Excel, but am unable to figure out how to do it in GS :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think only choice you have is to `clear and reapply` the borders.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Bahwani, as you can see in my screenshot there are different borders (color & thickness) for a cell. With your proposal, how do I apply different borders to a cell? Example: left border should be fat and black whilst top and right should be thin and green and at the bottom there should be no border at all. In Excel this can be configured, but how is it done with GS?

Comment: @mortpiedra after clearing the border, you can achieve any type of borders you want, you can change the thickness and color of the border too, have updated the answer please check.